# trigger click event on formly-field for formly in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to trigger click event from formly field , to get some data for that particular field, i have tried hard.. but unable to find any type of solution.
Help me. I am trying this from two days.

Comment: What have you tried? What is a simple version of your code that still demonstrates the problem? Can you construct an example in jsFiddle, Plunkr or similar?

Comment: Please include a minimal, complete, verifiable example in your question. In other words, include your codes even if they are not working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is a plunker link  http://plnkr.co/edit/rDJkSHLMGbpMdY0U6HPF?p=preview   , on which I am working with customized formly text template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. I have created a directive to bind teh click event with the element

```
  app.directive('formValue', [ '$compile','$parse','$timeout', function($compile,$parse,$timeout)   
{
return {
    restrict : "A",
    scope : false,
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {



        element.bind("click", function() {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                $parse( attrs.selectedItem ).assign(scope.$parent.$parent.$parent, angular.copy(scope.formProperties[input]));
                $parse(attrs.selectedIndex).assign(scope.$parent.$parent.$parent,attrs.elementIndex);

            });

        });


    },
    controller:"FormCtrl"
};

} ]);
```